# Im developing an app with apache cordova but i keep getting this error everytime i make an ajax request to a server on my LAN network

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, cordova

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.15.8/App/app_server.php No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I have already checked a lot of tutorials, i cant seem to resolve, im testing this inn my browser by the way

This is my index.html file just in case it helps

```
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
```

-->

native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link href="ratchet/css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/pageslider.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>SuppChain</title>
```

```
<script id="login" type="text/template">

    <div class="padding">
        <div class="padding">
            <p style="text-align:center"><img src="img/suppchain_logo.png"></p>
            <div style="text-align:center;" id="login_response"></div>

            <div class="list list-inset">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input id="given_email" type="text" placeholder="First  Name">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input id="given_password" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                </label>
            </div>
            <button id="login_button" class="button button-block button-positive">
                Sign In</button>

            <br>
            <p style="text-align:center">If You Dont Have an Account Yet Please
                <a href="/signup">Register</a></p>
            <br>
            <div id="spinner" style="text-align:center;display:none;"><img    src="img/spinner.gif" /></div>

        </div>
    </div>

</script>

<script id="supplier_dashboard_orders" class="slider_content" type="text/template">

    {{supplier_name}} {{supplier_email}}{{supplier_id}}

    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item">
            sljd/jdisjdoijdosjdopjsdpj
            <br> sklsdndlsknldnsdnklsdnlknd
        </li>
    </ul>

</script>

<script id="supplier_dashboard_clients" class="slider_content"     type="text/template">
    <div class="bar bar-header">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
        <div class="h1 title">Header Buttons</div>
        <button class="button button-clear button-positive">Edit</button>
    </div>
     <div class="content">Clients Page{{id}} {{name}}{{email}}{{password}}            </div>
    <nav class="bar bar-tab">
        <a class="tab-item " href="#orders">
            <span class="icon icon-home"></span>
            <span class="tab-label">Orders</span>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item active" href="#clients">
            <span class="icon icon-person"></span>
            <span class="tab-label">Clients</span>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
            <span class="icon icon-star-filled"></span>
            <span class="tab-label">Reports</span>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
            <span class="icon icon-search"></span>
            <span class="tab-label">Inventory</span>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
            <span class="icon icon-gear"></span>
            <span class="tab-label">Settings</span>
        </a>
    </nav>

</script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/pageslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/router.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/get_server.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/ionic.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @macphil, did you tried disabling web security while testing on chrome?

Comment: Wow ,i disabled web security for chrome and i worked, thank you

Comment: @macphil glad it worked.Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Here is more info recarding the CORS issue: [MDN HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

I also notice you are using the Ionic framework. Is this a custom setup you made or did you use the generator?

If you used the generator, Ionic can serve your app files and comes with proxy functionality, too: [Ionic Framework: Testing in a browser](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/test.html)

You'll need to add your backend address to the proxy and your CORS issue should be resolved without changing your browsers security settings.

You can also create this setup with NodeJS. Ionic uses NodeJS plugins to create this developer environment after all.